# Telling if matrix is contractive from the spectrum of its Choi-Jamiołkowski isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $T$ is a ${d^2}\times {d^2}$ [completely positive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_positive_map) matrix, and $M$ is ${d^2}\times {d^2}$ matrix obtained by taking Choi-Jamiołkowski isomorphism of $T$. Is it possible to tell if $T$ is [convergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_matrix) by looking at the spectrum of $M$?

Example:

$$M=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$T=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Eigenvalues of $M$ are ${1, 1/2, 0, 0}$, while eigenvalues of $T$ are $\left\{\frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{5}+1\right),-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4} \left(1-\sqrt{5}\right)\right\}$